# Code version change "rules"

Tags: version-control, project-management

I know that there are no fixed rules about software version control but I have several questions.

**1) How to upgrade versions correctly**

I have a small software that I started a while ago and since i started from scratch I started with version 0.1.

As I added more functionality I have been upgrading the minor number. Now I'm in v0.5.7 (minor (.5) for new functions and revision (.7) for bug fixes and minor changes), the thing is that the program is almost complete for distribution, but now I'm "missing" several minor versions, how do you guys handle that situation? do you simply just jump the numbers?

That brings me to the second question.

**2) Which is a good starting version number**

I am about to start a new project. This time is not that small of a project and is going to be public and free for modifying, I do not want to have the issues mentioned above. So which would be a good starting point?

Bonus question:

**3) Is it ok to make numbers above 10? like v1.25 or v2.2.30?**

I haven't seen software with that kind of numbering (probably they show it only in the help section or in their web-page), again I am aware that there are no rules for that but it seems to be that there is a general consent on how to keep the version numbers.

Comment: Software versioning isn't what is normally meant by 'version control' and I don't see anything to do with git here.

Comment: "I haven't seen software with that kind of numbering" - The latest Linux kernel version is 2.6.34.1

Comment: Yes, version can be anything you want, but must be logical (to tack).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Version numbering policies can be a bit crazy at times (see [Version numbers and JSR277](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2008/05/version-numbers-and-jsr277.html), or  [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html), with its Oracle Database 11g Release 2: `11.2.0.1.0`.
See also [Software Versioning is Ridiculous](http://aniszczyk.org/2009/11/19/software-versioning-is-ridiculous/)).

But you can start by looking at the [Eclipse Version Number policy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Version_Numbering) as a good start.
If you really think you need more than three digits, this [V.R.M.F. Maintenance Stream Delivery Vehicle terminology explanation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27008656) is also interesting, but more so for post 1.0 software programs, where fix pack and interim fixes are in order.

---

> 1. How to upgrade versions correctly

"Ship it already": `1.0.0`

Also known as the "`1.oh-oh`" version. At least, it is out there, and you can begin to get feedback and iterate *fast*.

> 2. Which is a good starting version number

`0.x` if *major* features are still missing; `1.0.0` if the major features are there.

> 3. Is it ok to make numbers above 10? like v1.25 or v2.2.30?

Yes, but I would say only for large projects with a lifespan over several years (a decade usually)

---

Note that "correctly" (while being described at length in [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](http://semver.org/)) can also be guided by more pragmatic factors:

See the [announcement for Git 1.9 (January 2014)](https://lists.q42.co.uk/pipermail/git-announce/2014-January/000647.html):

> A release candidate Git v1.9-rc2 is now available for testing at the usual places.
>
> **I've heard rumours that various third-party tools do not like the two-digit version numbers** (e.g. "Git 2.0") **and started barfing left and right** when the users install v1.9-rc1.
> While it is tempting to laugh at them for their sloppy assumption, I am also practical and
> do not mind calling the upcoming release v1.9.0 to help them.
>
> If we go that route (and I am inclined to go that route at this moment), the versioning scheme will be:
>
> - The next release candidate will be `v1.9.0-rc3`, not `v1.9-rc3`;
> - The first maintenance release for `v1.9.0` will be `v1.9.1` (and Nth one be `v1.9.N`); and
> - The feature release after v1.9.0 will be either v1.10.0 or v2.0.0, depending on how big the feature jump we are looking at.

---

Update Feb. 2019: semver itself is about to evolve (again, after semver2).
See "[What’s next for SemVer](https://words.steveklabnik.com/what-s-next-for-semver#fnref2)", and [`semver/semver/CONTRIBUTING`](https://github.com/semver/semver/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: http://semver.org/ : semantic versioning, is an interesting source.

Comment: Semantic Versioning is about versioning APIs, not programs.

Comment: @PolymorphicPotato I feel that people frequently forget that if you declare any public methods or functions, you have declared an api for that code you just wrote. Often these internal-use apis may not be treated as first class apis, bundled with a larger application that has no public api per se, but that application as a whole may still be versioned. I Personally feel that semantic versions applies well to applications. Additionally people so-so-so often use the term API to refer to and only to REST API's. :\

Answer (score 7):

At our company, we are using four token versioning concept. It's something like **a.b.c.d** kind:

```
(major).(feature).(revision).(bug/refactoring)
```

It's related with issue types which we use in our development life cycle. We can track what has done or changed between two following versions at a glance. By comparing two following version numbers you can identify number and types of issues done.
For more information, [full documentation is here.](https://csonuryilmaz.github.io/software/versioning/2018/03/24/software-versioning.html)

Comment: @csonuryilmaz, good point! And using git-flow to control this tasks?

Comment: Thanks @GabrielSimas . We're using **redmine** for issue/task tracking and we have a continuous integration pipeline which handles version number automatically by looking at issues/tasks. I've edited and fixed the dead link above so you can visit for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Even i faced this problem with defining the version number while developing with CRM, since i wanted to deploy the same build across all the systems. I found a way to resolve it with System value + Manual + randoms.

The version information for an assembly consists of four values:

**Major Version** . **Minor Version** . **Build Number** . **Revision**

Which makes the initial Version 1.0.0.0 by default. To make more sense i replace it with

**TFS Release** . **TFS Sprint** . **Change Number** . **Incremented build number**

Suppose in your TFS a single release consists 30 sprints and after that the release becomes 2, so the values for the first release will be:

**TFS Release** : 1

If the current sprint is 4, the TFS Sprint will have

**TFS Sprint** : 4

Now the third part is managed by the developer, for a initial version we can have 0 which can be incremented +1 for each ChangeRequest or BugFix.

**Change Number**: 0   -- represent initial version
**Change Number**: 1   -- represent change
**Change Numbe**r: 2   -- represent bugfix

Although for every bugfix there might be a change in code, so it represents the code change as default. But to more more sense you can have the odd number to represent the change and even number to represent the bugfix.

The last part was the default number, thankfully .Net allows us to put * to put a default build number. It keeps on increment with every compile/build which provides a signature stamp, if someone else rebuilds it changes.

***How to Implement:***

Open the AssemblyInfo.cs in the Properties folder and Comment the AssemblyFileVersion, this will make the AssemblyFileVersion & AssemblyVersion same.

```
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.4.2.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

So the final version will come out as: **1.4.2.4512** or something

The benefits of this approach is that you can track the Task for which the code is generated. Just by looking at the version number i can say, "Hey its the release  1 for sprint 4 and with some code change.

Comment: I do not agree with your TFS example. The Scrum iterations might add compatibility issues between one sprint to the other to include a feature or change not planned at the beginning of the project and you will face a versioning challenge to increase the Major Version to avoid integration issues. The idea of semantic versioning is to identify changes between releases to avoid compatibility issues, your idea is most suitable for commercial purposes as Microsoft does with windows, where you have the a Commercial version( Win 7, Win8, Win8.1) but under the hood they have different file versions.

Comment: I guess the features are not planned at the beginning of the project(hardly true) since it all depends on the business requirements. and if the requirements comes for the major feature(a complete new module) that takes say 20 sprints then YES, That will create the major version to increase as 2.1.x.x after the current release. I can't understand the integration issues you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

[Semantic Versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377655/code-version-change-rules#comment13050865_3377717) is pretty much de facto nowadays.

> I'm "missing" several minor versions, how do you guys handle that situation?

You're not missing versions. It's perfectly acceptable to… (see next answer)

> Which is a good starting version number

Depends if people are using your code in production. If it's already used in production jump straight to `v1.0.0`. But since you said your code is *alpha*, *beta*, or *rc* (release candidate) quality but you're planning to move to production quickly consider starting with `v1.0.0-[alpha].N` where `[alpha]` is the software grade and `N` is a build number or other enumerable value.

> Is it ok to make numbers above 10? like v1.25 or v2.2.30?

That's the idea. Lexicographical sorting may not work but that's okay.