# How to setup version control with following features?

Tags: version-control

1. Hosted on a server running Windows.
2. WebUI which allows to host a complete distributive(Java) of a master branch.
3. Version numbering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [**Bonobo Git Server**](http://bonobogitserver.com/) in order to manage Git repo.

Your repos will be distributed by the very nature of the [DVCS (Distributed Version Control System) which is Git](http://git-scm.com/).
For more, see:

- "[Sell me Distributed revision control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563917/6309)", and
- "[Describe your workflow of using version control (VCS or DVCS)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705286/6309)".

The version numbering is done by tag, and the policy is left to you: see "[Code version change “rules”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377717/6309)".